# Linq to Xml selecting elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Calendar>
    <item id="34">
      <Date>26 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aa</Name>
      <Date>26 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaa</Name>
      <Date>23 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaaa</Name>
      <Date>23 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaaaa</Name>    
    </item>  
    <item id="35">
      <Date>27 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aa</Name>
      <Date>27 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaa</Name>
      <Date>27 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaaa</Name>
      <Date>27 Apr</Date>
      <Name>aaaaa</Name>    
    </item>  
</Calendar>
```

this is my class

```
public class Calendar
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }

    }


listBox.ItemsSource = 
from var in xml.Descendants("item")
orderby Convert.ToInt32(var.Attribute("id").Value) ascending
select new Calendar
   {
        Name= var.Element("Name").Value,
        Data = var.Element("Data ").Value,

};
```

but in listBox i have only the first date and name of every item

Comment: don't use `var` for variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
  XDocument xml =
    XDocument.Load(
      @"Path to your xml");

  var q = from x in xml.Descendants("item")
          orderby Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("id").Value) ascending
          select new Calendar
                   {
                     Name = x.Elements("Name").Select(a => a.Value).ToList<String>(),
                     Date = x.Elements("Date").Select(a => a.Value).ToList<String>()
                   };

  List<Calendar> calendars = q.ToList<Calendar>();
}

public class Calendar
{
  public List<String> Name { get; set; }
  public List<String> Date { get; set; }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[`XElement.Element(elementName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) only gets the first element that matches the elementName. Try a different approach using [`XElement.Elements(elementName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx)